# How to compare date in PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I have a field in PostgreSQL that has: 
"timestamp with time zone compare"

I need to use a data range comparaison from JS

```
var start = Date.UTC(2012,02,30);//1333065600000

var end = Date.UTC(2013,02,30); //1364601600000
```

that results in bigint numbers:

How to use start(1333065600000) and end (1364601600000) inside sql PostgreSQL request ?

Comment: The _valueOf JavaScript Dates_ are the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch, `Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

Comment: Use `to_timestamp()` to convert from unix epoch to timestamps. Example: `to_timestamp(1333065600000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select *
from my_table
where date_field between to_timestamp(1333065600000) and to_timestamp(1364601600000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as `TO_TIMESTAMP`, but converts to UTC time zone if the server is not running at UTC.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN
   ((TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1333065600 * INTERVAL '1 second') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
   AND
   ((TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1364601600 * INTERVAL '1 second') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
```

Please note that Javascript epoch accuracy is milliseconds, while Unix epoch is only seconds. You have to either discard last three digits from the input values (like I did in the example above), or divide by 1000 (example below).

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1333065600000/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second') AT TIME ZONE UTC;
```